# Why Address (lower word of address) of a function is always same in every execution

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, operating-system, function-pointers

I have made following code in main()

```
int (*Addition)(int x, int y) = FuncAdd;

cout<<endl<<"Address of Addition is: "<<Addition<<endl;
```

Now every-time I execute it. I get values like this:

> Address of Addition is: 01161450
>
> Address of Addition is: 001B1450
>
> Address of Addition is: 00F91450

and so on..

As we can see, address is different every time, though there is lower word (1450-H) common among all of them. So whats the reason behind it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address of the function was defined by the compiler and linker relative to the start of the program space. However the OS is free to load the program starting anywhere it desires, and due to [Address Space Layout Randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) it will change with every run. It appears your OS uses a starting address that is a multiple of 0x10000.

Answer (score 1):

The OS divides the memory into several partitions. If every partition starts from `xxxx0000 H`,
it appears that your `FuncAdd()` segment is allocated after `1450 H` memory positions. It may vary due to change in length of other functions and other declarations, because the segments allocated previously determine the starting segment address of `FuncAdd()`.

Comment: Still living in a 16 bit world eh?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, the OS is allocating your program a different memory location from a flat memory model. So, FuncAdd()'s address can change each time. The previously allocated space will eventually be reclaimed/reused by the loader. If you try this in an OS such as Linux/Unix where memory model is virtual, you should always get a same value for FuncAdd()
I also added another function FuncAdd2() for illustration.

try this on a linux:

```
int FuncAdd (int x, int y){ return 0;}
int FuncAdd2 (int x, int y){return 0;}
typedef  int (*fp)(int, int);
fp Addition[2];
    int main()
    {

        Addition[0] = FuncAdd;
        Addition[1] = FuncAdd2;
        printf("\nAddress of *addition is %X " , Addition[0] );
        printf("\nAddress of *addition1 is %X\n ", Addition[1]);
    }
```

You will get this SAME (in Linux like OS)
Address of *addition is 80483E4 << This is a relative address to the proc and remains same
Address of *addition1 is 80483EE <

Comment: the moral is, your experiment shows the memory model used for applications by the OS